# Keeping state of component after refresh

Tags: c#, refresh, state, blazor

Hello i am wondering how can you keep state of a component variable in Blazor without using different pages.
Lets say i have a `Parent` page that has a `Login` component :

**Login**

```
 @functions()
   {
   public Action<string>onlogin{get;set;}  //some logic that triggers this event to the parent , ---not important
   }
```

**Main**

```
@if(this.id==string.Empty)
{
<Login onlogin="@((value)=>OnLoginEvent(value))"></Login>
}

@functions()
{
 public string id{get;set;}=string.Empty;
 public void OnLoginEvent(string value)
 {
   this.id=value;
 }
```

Now as you can see ,the first time i render the `Main` component and i log in , the `id` will become be different from `string.Empty`, and so the `Login` component will then disappear.
However if i refresh the page , i am still back  with the `login` component rendered ,so the `id`  is resetted.

Can i somehow keep the state of a `Component` variable even after refresh ? In this case i want to keep `id` from being `string.Empty` even after refresh?

**P.S** I do not want to use different pages , and i was thinking as a solution to store the value of `id` in a `service` that is injected.Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A service would be a good way to solve your problem, as you've concluded. But another option would be to use the browsers local storage. This would persist your data in a very robust way. You can use a library such as this one [BlazoredLocalStorage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlazoredLocalStorage/) (Full disclosure, I'm the author).

This method would persist the data outside of a users session though, so, for example, a user could close the browser and come back a day later and the data would still be present. So you would have to manage that. But this is how many SPA applications handle this problem.

Comment: What if you needed the data in another service where you can't call the OnAfterRenderAsync?

Comment: Blazored LocalStorage exposes the Local Storage API's via a C# class you can inject into a component or a service. You need to make sure your service is only making calls to local storage when it's available, I.E. after the app has booted and JS interop is available.